# Returning most common linked ID for a user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. The `user_sticker` holds all sent stickers between users. When the profile view screen is loaded, i need to display which is the most common sticker that has been given to the user.

**user**

- id_user
- name

**sticker**

- id_sticker
- name

**user_sticker**

- id_user_sticker
- id_sticker
- id_user_from
- id_user_to

So, if `user_sticker` holds this info:

- 1, 3, 254, 205
- 2, 2, 362, 205
- 3, 2, 519, 205
- 4, 3, 945, 205
- 5, 3, 199, 205

(which means that users 254, 362, 519, 945, 199 sent stickers to user 205).
The result has to return **both** the user 205 information (Name) and the most common sticker id (in this case #3) in the same record.

Comment: Do you need it for **all** receiving users or just for a certain **one**?

Comment: just for a specified user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets see

In principal, you need to use the user_sticker table. So:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_sticker us
```

Then, match with the user table for user_to

```
SELECT *
FROM user_sticker us JOIN user u ON us.id_user_to = u.id_user
```

Then, you want the name and the stickers the user you want recieve

```
SELECT us.id_sticker, u.name
FROM user_sticker us JOIN user u ON us.id_user_to = u.id_user
WHERE u.id_user = "yourwanteduser"
```

Now, pick the first

```
SELECT TOP 1 us.id_sticker, u.name
FROM user_sticker us JOIN user u ON us.id_user_to = u.id_user
WHERE u.id_user = "yourwanteduser"
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM user_sticker us2
          WHERE us2.id_user_to=u.id_user AND us2.id_sticker=us.id_sticker)
```

The ORDER BY is used to search how many of the stickers were sent to that user

Sorry for my bad english! I hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

this would be the select:

```
   select id_user_to, count(id_sticker) quant from user_sticker group by id_sticker order by quant desc limit 1;
```

now with the info of the user: JOIN

```
select us.id_user_to, u.name, count(us.id_sticker) quant 
from user_sticker us
join user u on u.id_user=us.id_user_to
group by us.id_sticker 
order by quant desc limit 1;
```

Comment: this query doesn't bring the user's Name, which is important for the original example.

Comment: Now I include a Join whit the users table in the sentence to bring the data of the user

Comment: Judging from the question it should have `WHERE us.id_user_to = 205` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select test.id_sticker, test.id_user_to, name from 
(select s.id_sticker, s.id_user_to
from user_sticker s, user u
group by id_sticker, id_user_to
order by count(*) desc
limit 1) 
as test, user
where test.id_user_to=user.id_user
```

See sql fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e02ca/6/0

Comment: exactly. but it has to be returned with the user info as well.

Comment: this query doesn't bring the user's Name, which is important for the original example.

Comment: username added :) with use of subquery